# i am using in my asp.net page and tried to set the iframe height 100%, But its does not work

Tags: asp.net, html, height

I am using in my asp.net page and tried to set the iframe height 100%, But its does not work.

Comment: Please copy the non-working aspx into your question.

Comment: no thanks man i find the solution and its working..thanks lot

Comment: Please do check my code ..i posted it as an answer

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, div, iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
  iframe { display:block; width:100%; border:none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably bounded by its parent's height. Set all ancestors to 100%, including the body and html tags if you want it to be the height of the window.

Comment: It snot working please tried it in ur page...i am changed all other parent tags style="height:100%".